# Using wget to Fetch Videos that are Linked to Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wget

I live in a rural area with a very spotty wireless ISP, so streaming content (especially hours of video tutorials) is a painful process. I'd LOVE to be able to have the videos fetched while sleeping to be reviewed the next day. So, I'm attempting to use wget to fetch the files from links.txt to store them locally and then simply use a cron job to schedule it for me. Unfortunately, there is a hiccup:

```
wget --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data 'username=user&password=pwd' \ 
-erobots=off --secure-protocol=SSLv3 --no-check-certificate \
https://www.domain.com/login.aspx

wget --load-cookies cookies.txt --content-disposition 
--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) \
Gecko/2008092416 Firefox/3.0.3" -l1 -H -t1 -nd -N -np -r -A.mp4 \
-erobots=off -w5 -i ../links.txt
```

The first command successfully fetches the website cookie information and stories it in the respective cookies.txt. The latter enabled me to successfully login to the website and start fetching content; however, it is only retrieving the page.html (and then discarding it due to the -r A.mp4 flags as anticipated). Unfortunately, it is not resolving the dynamic links in page.html in order to fetch the `RandomGeneratedFilename.mp4` content that I need. Is there something that I'm missing?

Even when I had it fetch the page.html file, the link doesn't have the filename/extension in the `href="a/dynamic/path"` so it makes sense why it isn't able to save the .mp4. But, how can I get wget to recursively follow that href to determine the appropriate filename and save it?

Thankfully, StackOverflow and Google have gotten me this far in figuring out the correct flags to pass thus far and how to successfully authenticate, but I'm not having any luck figuring out the last step. I'm *guessing* that I'm going to have to write a bash script and use a combination of awk and sed to do this, but I honestly am not sure...

Currently I'm using a browser plugin to do this and it's a very manual process. I might as well just stream the video and watch it through the website at this point which, as stated, is not very practical in my situation. :(

I'd truly appreciate any time and insight you all may have to offer as this would be a huge boon! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, after using Inspect and reviewing the source code it's clear that they are obfuscating the links for a reason; so, I did my due diligence and read the TOS. It's a violation of the TOS to do what I'm attempting to do, so I'm going to abandon this question at this point. They are paying for the CDN and it's resources, so they don't want it to be abused (albeit that wasn't my intention). Nonetheless, it's in violation so this is mute point. I'd still be interested in finding out how to do this for other sites, but I'll wait to find a site that doesn't prohibit it before digging deeper.